# Compile the Linux kernel using LLVM

Tags: llvm, riscv

We want to port Linux for single-core RISCV processor on FPGA. Meanwhile, the Linux kernel will be instrumented by LLVM pass.

My doubts are:
1. Whether the riscv-llvm toolchain could be used to compile the Linux kernel?
2. Whether the riscv-llvm toolchain now supports adding custom pass?

Comment: Recent versions of Linux kernel may be buildable by llvm (there was project http://llvm.linuxfoundation.org/ to enable this; some modules/options were not compilable some time ago). What is the version of linux kernel and llvm used in your project? You can add custom passes to any llvm, and there are sources for llvm for riscv.

Comment: We want to use Linux kernel-2.6.33. I am a complete beginner to compiling linux kernel. Could you please give me some tutorial or suggestion about the process?

Comment: Rambo, is there linux kernel 2.6.33 for RISC-V? I think there is only version https://github.com/riscv/riscv-linux which is not 2.6 but 3.14 / 4.1. You can't just compile that old kernel; the porting to RISC-V will be needed, which is not task to beginner.

Comment: Why 2.6.33? It is even not LTS (2.6.32 was untill feb 2016), it 6 year old.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind respons. At the beginning, we wanted to realize my design based on RISCV processor on FPGA. Now, we dicide to do it based on gem5 simulator. I have a hardware background (VLSI design). Now, I want to realize a computer achitecture project ( including OS, simulator, compiler...). So I have to face so many challenges. I use the Linux kernel-2.6.33 for my initial experiments, so I choose it. The hear of matter is how to compile Linux kernel with LLVM, and write a pass to generate the target address of indrect jump/call instructions.

Comment: Rambo, where are you from? Do you have OS/compiler experience, or it is university project? There is no working public gem5 of RISC-V.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with chosen Linux version, 2.6.33.

First problem is that this version was never ported to RISC-V by RISC-V team. They have 3.14 and 4.1 in https://github.com/riscv/riscv-linux. So, to start it in RISC-V processor, you should repeat all porting of architecture-dependent part (`arch/` directory of the kernel). This is *very complex task*, even when there is some ported version for target CPU. You may backport some parts from 3.14, but 2.6.33 and 3.14 are different, there were several years of evolution between them.  (PORTING is not just COMPILING, it is task of writing 30 files without any errors, or with long debugging.)

Second problem is that LLVM can only fully build modern Linux kernel versions which has patches from http://llvm.linuxfoundation.org/ project. There were unsupported (and never-to-be-supported in clang/llvm) GCC extensions used in some parts of the kernel. Partial build was possible, but two-three components of older Linux can't be build with clang.

So, I really recommend you to used linux kernel version from RISCV team, and newer (4.1) is better.